# How to sort value existing columns by another column?

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I am trying to sort the existing columns in pandas by another.
Here's the output of my pandas dataset

```
d_id a  b   c   d   sort_d_id
3    1  1   0   0   53
21   0  0   0   1   32
32   0  1   0   1   32
32   0  1   0   1   3
53   0  0   1   0   21
```

basically, I want to sort d_id by sort_d_did.
The outcome I want is

```
d_id a  b   c   d   sort_d_id
53   0  0   1   0   53
32   0  1   0   1   32
32   0  1   0   1   32
3    1  1   0   0   3
21   0  0   0   1   21
```

Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: So you want to sort them as strings, not integers?

Comment: Check the documentation for `df.sort_values` [(link)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html).

Comment: I cannot access the link @AJH.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html Does this work?

Comment: I try with sort_values(by='sort_d_id') but it doesn't work.

Comment: @BeRT2me, yes I just want it get it sort. But yes, the value are integers.

Comment: is `d_id` the index?

Comment: no it's not the index. it's directory id. but dirs are sorted differently in another machines so I am trying to match that sorting by sort_d_id. @enke.

Comment: You could also try: `df.set_index('d_id').loc[df['sort_d_id']].drop_duplicates()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how to do it:

```
# Get the d_id and sort_d_id columns for easy handling and rearranging
sort_d_id = df["sort_d_id"].tolist()
d_id = df["d_id"].tolist()

# Also get the row indices (i.e. 0 to 4) in order.
indices = list(range(len(d_id)))

# The 1st column of arr will be indices, 2nd column is sort_d_id, 3rd column is d_id.
arr = np.array([indices, sort_d_id, d_id]).T

# Sort columns according to sort_d_id.
arr = arr[np.argsort(arr[:, 1])]

# The order is now the d_id indices mapped to the sort_id_indices
# e.g. d_id[0] will become d_id[3], d_id[1] will become d_id[4], etc.
new_order = arr[:, 0]

# But we don't want that; we want sort_d_id mapped to the d_id indices.
# So we do another reordering and get the new indices.
new_order_zipped = sorted(zip(new_order, indices))
final_order = list(map(list, zip(*new_order_zipped)))[1]

# Reorder by the final indices.
df = df.reindex(final_order)

# Replace the sort_d_id column which got messed up during reordering.
df["sort_d_id"] = sort_d_id

# Reset indices if you want
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

The resulting `df` now looks how it should. It's rather confusing, I know, but it does work as it should.

Comment: The other columns get sorted as well. The `df` I get looks exactly like your desired output. Are you using the same exact `df` you posted, or are you using one with more rows?

Comment: Before the `arr[np.argsort]` line, what do you get if you do `print(arr)`? Also, do you think you could try running the code in Google Colab? I'm using Colab, so maybe it's a machine-specific thing. What versions of `pandas` and `numpy` do you have?

Comment: sry, I miscopied some of your code. Thank you so much @AJH

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can figure to get your desired output is:

```
df_1 = df['sort_d_id'].sort_values(ascending=False, key=lambda x: x.astype('string'))
df_2 = df.drop('sort_d_id', axis=1).sort_values('d_id', ascending=False, key=lambda x: x.astype('string')).reset_index(drop=True)
df = pd.concat([df_1, df_2], axis=1,)[df.columns]
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   d_id  a  b  c  d  sort_d_id
0    53  0  0  1  0         53
1    32  0  1  0  1         32
2    32  0  1  0  1         32
3     3  1  1  0  0          3
4    21  0  0  0  1         21
```